# How to convert Lambda into simple Java function

Tags: java, lambda

I am trying to understand a program in java which has used lambda to return object into the reference variable of an interface. I want to convert lambda into simple java function, but not sure how to do it.

The program is as follows:

```java
public abstract class Performance implements Serializable
{ 
    InterfaceName vehicle =(InterfaceName & Serializable) () ->{return new Object();};
    Object speed() 
    {
        return vehicle.speed();
    }
}
```

The interface is as follows:-

```
public interface InterfaceName 
{
    Object speed();
}
```

How could I convert this program into a simple Java program without use of a lambda, as a learning exercise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace lambda expression with your own implementation of the `InterfaceName` interface.

```
class InterfaceNameImpl implements InterfaceName {
    @Override
    public Object speed() {
        return new Object();
    }
}
```

Subsequently, you can replace your statement that uses lambda expression with

```
InterfaceName vehicle = new InterfaceNameImpl();
```

You can even use anonymous classes without explicitly having the above class that implements `InterfaceName`

```
InterfaceName vehicle1 = new InterfaceName() {
    @Override
    public Object speed() {
        return new Object();
    }
};
```

On a different note, you could even simplify your lambda usage from

```
InterfaceName vehicle =(InterfaceName & Serializable) () ->{return new Object();};
```

to

```
InterfaceName vehicle = () -> new Object();
```

or an even shorter version is

```
InterfaceName vehicle = Object::new;
```

In case, you want to understand how lambdas are implemented internally by the compiler you can go through [Java-8-Lambdas-A-Peek-Under-the-Hood](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-8-Lambdas-A-Peek-Under-the-Hood)

Comment: Thanks a lot Madhusudana. This is really helpful. I want to ask you that does typecasting to (InterfaceName & Serializable) makes any difference or not and what is (&) doing here.

Comment: @ela If you use with both `vehicle =(InterfaceName & Serializable)...`, it allows us to typecast `vehicle` to either of the above types.You can test the same with using `instanceof` operator on `vehicle` and it would return true for both. Anyways, if you don't use `(InterfaceName & Serializable)` it can't be typecasted to Serializable and only be typecasted to `InterfaceName`.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the field entirely. This is the same:

```
public abstract class Performance implements InterfaceName {
    Object speed() {
        return new Object();
    }
}
```